# Integral with Limit and Parameters

Tags: integration

I am stuck on the following problem evaluating an integral with parameters, where the parameter has a limit:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \sin \left(e^{xt}\right)\,dt$$

I know that in some cases you can differentiate what is contained within the integral, which gives us, $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \int_0^\infty t  e^{xt}\cos \left(e^{xt}\right)\,dt$, which, with a $u$-substitution leads to $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \int_1^\infty \cos \left(u\right)\,dt$, but I don't know for sure that I can do that in this case or what to do from there.

Comment: See the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 4):

Change variables as $u = e^{xt}$.

Then

$$\left|\int_0^{\infty} \sin(e^{xt})\,dt\right| = \left|\frac1{x}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}\, du\right|$$

The integral on the RHS converges. Integrating by parts,

$$\left|\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}\, du\right|= \left|\cos(1) - \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos u}{u^2}\, du\right|< \cos(1) + \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2}\, du<\infty$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^{\infty} \sin(e^{xt})\,dt=0$$

Comment: It is an improper Riemann integral and converges in that sense. However, it is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @robjohn - yes its not absolutely integrable. But I'm not using that. $\left|\frac1{x}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}\, du\right|$ = (finite number)$/|x| \to 0$.